# Cual deberia ser la estructura correcta en formato Json para enviar el archivo al facturador SFS

Tags: json

tengo mi propio sistema y tengo instalado el facturador de la SUNAT me fui por el camino de crear el archivo en formato **JSON**, entonces quiero saber cual es la estructura que debo crear para cuando lo pase a la carpeta DATA genere el comprobante y se envié correctamente. Espero de su ayuda muchas gracias. Estoy utilizando la versión SFS_v1.3.4.2

Ejemplo tengo lo siguiente:

```
  $data = array(
            "tipo_de_comprobante"               => $tipoDoc,
            "serie"                             => $serie,
            "numero"                            => (string)$correlativo,
            "sunat_transaction"                 => "1", // Venta interna
            "cliente_tipo_de_documento"         =>$cliente_tipo_de_documento,
            "cliente_numero_de_documento"       => $cliente_numero_de_documento,
            "cliente_denominacion"              => $cliente_denominacion,
            "cliente_direccion"                 => $direccion,
            "cliente_email"                     => $cliente_email,
            "cliente_email_1"                   => "",
            "cliente_email_2"                   => "",
            "fecha_de_emision"                  => $fechaEmision,
            "fecha_de_vencimiento"              => "",
            "moneda"                            => "1", //SOLES
            "tipo_de_cambio"                    => "",
            "porcentaje_de_igv"                 => "18.00",
            "descuento_global"                  => $descuento,
            "total_descuento"                   => $descuento,
            "total_anticipo"                    => "",
            "total_gravada"                     => $subtotal,
            "total_inafecta"                    => "",
            "total_exonerada"                   => "",
            "total_igv"                         => $igv,
            "total_gratuita"                    => "",
            "total_otros_cargos"                => "",
            "total"                             => $total,
            "percepcion_tipo"                   => "",
            "percepcion_base_imponible"         => "",
            "total_percepcion"                  => "",
            "total_incluido_percepcion"         => "",
            "detraccion"                        => "false",
            "observaciones"                     => "",
            "documento_que_se_modifica_tipo"    => "",
            "documento_que_se_modifica_serie"   => "",
            "documento_que_se_modifica_numero"  => "",
            "tipo_de_nota_de_credito"           => "",
            "tipo_de_nota_de_debito"            => "",
            "enviar_automaticamente_a_la_sunat" => "true",
            "enviar_automaticamente_al_cliente" => "true",
            "codigo_unico"                      => "",
            "condiciones_de_pago"               => "",
            "medio_de_pago"                     => ucfirst($metodoPago),
            "placa_vehiculo"                    => "",
            "orden_compra_servicio"             => "",
            "tabla_personalizada_codigo"        => "",
            "formato_de_pdf"                    => $formato,
            'items'                             => $items

        );

        $data_json = json_encode($data);
```

$file = '20000000000-01-F001-19.json';

Pero esos valores no estoy muy seguro de cuales son los que la SUNAT requiera para validar el XML

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Si la pregunta es sobre una integración específica con un tercero, la solución pasa por la documentación/soporte de ese tercero. Si tienes un código que no se comporta como debe y tienes errores/problemas, puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/411894/edit) tu pregunta y añadir el código y los errores (como texto). De otra forma, esta pregunta bien puede terminar cerrada porque no tiene un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y se basa más en opiniones que en respuestas puntuales a una pregunta puntual.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la respuesta el facturador SFS LA estructura en formato JSON según el anexo 1 y 2 publicado en su pagina oficial indica cuales son los atributos.
Ejemplo de como debería quedar sacado de la misma página espero a alguien le sirva:

```html
{
    "cabecera" : {
        "tipOperacion" : "0101",
        "fecEmision" : "2018-08-22",
        "horEmision" : "12:12:14",
        "fecVencimiento" : "2018-12-22",
        "codLocalEmisor" : "0000",
        "tipDocUsuario" : "6",
        "numDocUsuario" : "20131312955",
        "rznSocialUsuario" : "SUNAT & COMPAÑÍA",
        "tipMoneda" : "PEN",
        "sumTotTributos" : "38.36",
        "sumTotValVenta" : "200.00",
        "sumPrecioVenta" : "238.36",
        "sumDescTotal" : "0.00",
        "sumOtrosCargos" : "0.00",
        "sumTotalAnticipos" : "0.00",
        "sumImpVenta" : "238.36",
        "ublVersionId" : "2.1",
        "customizationId" : "2.0"
    },
    "variablesGlobales" : [{
            "tipVariableGlobal" : "true",
            "codTipoVariableGlobal" : "51",
            "porVariableGlobal" : "0.03",
            "monMontoVariableGlobal" : "PEN",
            "mtoVariableGlobal" : "3.00",
            "monBaseImponibleVariableGlobal" : "PEN",
            "mtoBaseImpVariableGlobal" : "100.00"
        },
        {
            "tipVariableGlobal" : "true",
            "codTipoVariableGlobal" : "50",
            "porVariableGlobal" : "0.01",
            "monMontoVariableGlobal" : "PEN",
            "mtoVariableGlobal" : "1.00",
            "monBaseImponibleVariableGlobal" : "PEN",
            "mtoBaseImpVariableGlobal" : "100.00"
        }
    ],
    "detalle" : [{
            "codUnidadMedida" : "NIU",
            "ctdUnidadItem" : "1",
            "codProducto" : "COD001",
            "codProductoSUNAT" : "",
            "desItem" : "ITEM 1 - Sujeto a detraciones. Características: 1.- En variablesGlobales se informan dos cargos (true) 50 Cargos globales que no afectan la base imponible del IGV IVAP y 51 Percepción venta interna",
            "mtoValorUnitario" : "100.00",
            "sumTotTributosItem" : "18.00",
            
            "codTriIGV" : "1000",
            "mtoIgvItem" : "18.00",
            "mtoBaseIgvItem" : "100.00",
            "nomTributoIgvItem" : "IGV",
            "codTipTributoIgvItem" : "VAT",         
            "tipAfeIGV" : "10",
            "porIgvItem" : "18.00",
            
            "codTriISC" : "-",
            "mtoIscItem" : "0.00",
            "mtoBaseIscItem" : "0.00",
            "nomTributoIscItem" : "ISC",
            "codTipTributoIscItem" : "EXC",
            "tipSisISC" : "1",
            "porIscItem" : "0.00",
            
            "mtoPrecioVentaUnitario" : "118.00",
            "mtoValorVentaItem" : "100",
            "mtoValorReferencialUnitario" : "0.00"
        }, {
            "codUnidadMedida" : "NIU",
            "ctdUnidadItem" : "1",
            "codProducto" : "COD002",
            "codProductoSUNAT" : "",
            "desItem" : "ITEM 2 - gastos de combustible. Caracterísitcas: 1.- Afecto a ISC e IGV(ver que tambien informamos en el conjunto 'tributos' los totales de IGV e ISC. 2.- En adicionalDetalle se agrega informacion de Detracciones, hospedaje.",
            "mtoValorUnitario" : "100.00",
            "sumTotTributosItem" : "20.36",
            
            "codTriIGV" : "1000",
            "mtoIgvItem" : "18.36",
            "mtoBaseIgvItem" : "102.00",
            "nomTributoIgvItem" : "IGV",
            "codTipTributoIgvItem" : "VAT",
            "tipAfeIGV" : "10",
            "porIgvItem" : "18.00",
            
            "codTriISC" : "2000",
            "mtoIscItem" : "2.00",
            "mtoBaseIscItem" : "100.00",
            "nomTributoIscItem" : "ISC",
            "codTipTributoIscItem" : "EXC",
            "tipSisISC" : "01",
            "porIscItem" : "2.00",
            
            "mtoPrecioVentaUnitario" : "120.36",
            "mtoValorVentaItem" : "100",
            "mtoValorReferencialUnitario" : "0.00"
        }
    ],
    "leyendas" : [{
            "codLeyenda" : "1000",
            "desLeyenda" : "CIENTO DIECIOCHO CON 00 /100 SOLES"
        }
    ],
    "adicionalDetalle" : [{
            "idLinea" : "2",
            "nomPropiedad" : "Detracciones: Recursos Hidrobiológicos - Fecha de descarga",
            "codPropiedad" : "3005",
            "valPropiedad" : "",
            "fecInicioPropiedad" : "2018-07-02",
            "horInicioPropiedad" : "",
            "fecFinPropiedad" : "",
            "numDiasPropiedad" : ""
        }, {
            "idLinea" : "2",
            "nomPropiedad" : "Beneficio Hospedajes: Fecha de Salida del Establecimiento",
            "codPropiedad" : "4004",
            "valPropiedad" : "",
            "fecInicioPropiedad" : "2018-07-02",
            "fecFinPropiedad" : "2018-07-02",
            "numDiasPropiedad" : ""
        }, {
            "idLinea" : "2",
            "nomPropiedad" : "Beneficio Hospedajes: Hora de Inicio",
            "codPropiedad" : "4047",
            "valPropiedad" : "",
            "fecInicioPropiedad" : "",
            "horInicioPropiedad" : "07:00:00",
            "fecFinPropiedad" : "",
            "numDiasPropiedad" : ""
        }, {
            "idLinea" : "2",
            "nomPropiedad" : "Beneficio Hospedajes: Número de Días de Permanencia",
            "codPropiedad" : "4005",
            "valPropiedad" : "",
            "fecInicioPropiedad" : "",
            "horInicioPropiedad" : "",
            "fecFinPropiedad" : "",
            "numDiasPropiedad" : "12"
        }, {
            "idLinea" : "2",
            "nomPropiedad" : "Gastos Art. 37 Renta: N°ro de Placa",
            "codPropiedad" : "7000",
            "valPropiedad" : "B6F-045",
            "codBienPropiedad" : "-"
        }
    ],
    "tributos" : [{
            "ideTributo" : "1000",
            "nomTributo" : "IGV",
            "codTipTributo" : "VAT",
            "codCatTributo" : "S",
            "mtoBaseImponible" : "200.00",
            "mtoTributo" : "36.00"
        }, {
            "ideTributo" : "2000",
            "nomTributo" : "ISC",
            "codTipTributo" : "EXC",
            "codCatTributo" : "S",
            "mtoBaseImponible" : "118.00",
            "mtoTributo" : "2.36"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: tienes alguna referencia para guías de remisión?, creo que este ejemplo solo es válido para comprobantes, no estoy seguro

Answer (score 0):

Con la versiòn SFS 1.4:
Nombre dearchivo: $RUCEMISOR-01-F001-00000120.json

```
{
  "cabecera": {
    "tipOperacion": "0101",
    "fecEmision": "2022-01-22",
    "horEmision": "12:12:14",
    "fecVencimiento": "2022-01-25",
    "codLocalEmisor": "0000",
    "tipDocUsuario": "6",
    "numDocUsuario": "20131312955",
    "rznSocialUsuario": "SUNAT & COMPAÑÍA",
    "tipMoneda": "PEN",
    "sumTotTributos": "1522.22",
    "sumTotValVenta": "8456.80",
    "sumPrecioVenta": "9979.02",
    "sumDescTotal": "0.00",
    "sumOtrosCargos": "0.00",
    "sumTotalAnticipos": "0.00",
    "sumImpVenta": "9979.02",
    "ublVersionId": "2.1",
    "customizationId": "2.0"
  },
  "adicionalCabecera": {
    "ctaBancoNacionDetraccion": "",
    "codBienDetraccion": "",
    "porDetraccion": "",
    "mtoDetraccion": "",
    "codMedioPago": "",
    "codPaisCliente": "PE",
    "codUbigeoCliente": "07061",
    "desDireccionCliente": "Direcciòn Cimpleta",
    "codPaisEntrega": "PE",
    "codUbigeoEntrega": "07061",
    "desDireccionEntrega": "ASDSAD"
  },
  "detalle": [
    {
      "codUnidadMedida": "NIU",
      "ctdUnidadItem": "200",
      "codProducto": "COD001",
      "codProductoSUNAT": "-",
      "desItem": " Renovar Dominio - pcserviceperu.com + Gestionar DNS 1Year",
      "mtoValorUnitario": "42.284",
      "sumTotTributosItem": "1522.22",
      "codTriIGV": "1000",
      "mtoIgvItem": "1522.22",
      "mtoBaseIgvItem": "8456.8",
      "nomTributoIgvItem": "IGV",
      "codTipTributoIgvItem": "VAT",
      "tipAfeIGV": "10",
      "porIgvItem": "18.00",
      "codTriISC": "-",
      "mtoIscItem": "0",
      "mtoBaseIscItem": "0",
      "nomTributoIscItem": "-",
      "codTipTributoIscItem": "-",
      "tipSisISC": "-",
      "porIscItem": "0",
      "codTriOtro": "-",
      "mtoTriOtroItem": "0",
      "mtoBaseTriOtroItem": "0",
      "nomTributoOtroItem": "-",
      "codTipTributoOtroItem": "-",
      "porTriOtroItem": "0",
      "codTriIcbper": "-",
      "mtoTriIcbperItem": "0",
      "ctdBolsasTriIcbperItem": "0",
      "nomTributoIcbperItem": "-",
      "codTipTributoIcbperItem": "-",
      "mtoTriIcbperUnidad": "0",
      "mtoPrecioVentaUnitario": "49.90",
      "mtoValorVentaItem": "8456.80",
      "mtoValorReferencialUnitario": "0.00"
    }
  ],
  "leyendas": [
    {
      "codLeyenda": "1000",
      "desLeyenda": "CUCHUCIENTOS ASDASDALSD"
    }
  ],
  "tributos": [
    {
      "ideTributo": "1000",
      "nomTributo": "IGV",
      "codTipTributo": "VAT",
      "mtoBaseImponible": "8456.8",
      "mtoTributo": "1522.22"
    }
  ],
  "datoPago": {
        "formaPago": "Contado",
        "mtoNetoPendientePago": "9979.02",
        "tipMonedaMtoNetoPendientePag": "PEN"
    }
}
```